# Submit an Object from an Array from the view

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Let say in this example I´m using Spring MVC, and I´m rendering from my controller to the view a List of n A elements, then in my view I´m iterating that List and for every element I´m creating a form to submit with the changes of that specific A. Then in my controller I´m just configuring to receive an A. And in my view for every element of A I just adding the A.attribute for the name and ${iterator.attribute} for the value(The value it´s render with this expresion ok) of the input. But I dont know why When I submit one of this forms, in my controller I´m always receiving the A object with null attributes. Looks like the binding of the Object A it´s not quite ok, but still dont know why.

Any idea guys?

Comment: show some relevant code and exceptions - http://sscce.org/

Comment: No exceptions, just the object is serialize in the controller with null attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are your form fields named with A[numericIndex]? for example: 
(where A is your list)

```
<c:forEach items="${A}" varStatus="status">
   …

   <form:input path="A[${status.index }].attribute"/>
   …

</c:forEach>
```

Comment: yes, I did exactly like that, but instead of use <form:input> I´m just using <input name="A[${status.index }].attribute" /> but I understand that that´s cannot be the problem because if I send back the whole list works.